# Proof $G_n$ is an integer

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I've been reading the proof to Stormer-Lehmer's method and I'm stuck on a particular statement of [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1256067456). Specifically, is where $G_n$ is defined. The author states that it is clear that $G_n$ is an integer as it is a symmetric function with respect to $\alpha$, $\beta$, and the roots of unity. I don't see in which sense it is symmetric with respect to the roots of unity, nor how this allows us to prove $G_n$ is an integer. Could someone please clarify this statement for me ?

Source: [On a problem of Stormer](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1256067456)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\zeta = e^{2\pi i/n}$ to simplify the notation. Switching the roles of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the definition of $G_n$ gives us
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\prod_{h \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}}(\beta - \alpha \zeta^n) &= \prod_{h \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}}(-\zeta^{h})(\alpha - \zeta^h\beta) \\
&= \prod_{h \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}}(-\zeta^h)\prod_{h \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}}(\alpha - \zeta^h\beta) \\
&= \prod_{h \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}} (-\zeta^h) \cdot G_n.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
So in order to show that $G_n$ is symmetric in $\alpha,\beta$, it suffices to show that the product in the last line is equal to $1$. This is easy to check if $n = 1,2$. For $n > 2$, we write
$$\prod_{h \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}}(-\zeta^h) = (-1)^{\phi(n)}\prod_{h \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}}\zeta^h$$
and recall that $\phi(n)$ is even since $n > 2$, thus $(-1)^{\phi(n)} = 1$. Since $n > 2$, no primitive $n$-th root of unity is its own inverse, so pairing each $\zeta^h$ with its inverse shows that the the product on the right-hand side is $1$.

The function is symmetric in the roots of unity in the sense that if you permute the primitive $n$-th roots of unity in the product defining $G_n$, the result is also equal to $G_n$. In other words, if $\pi$ is any permutation of the elements of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, then
$$\prod_{h \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}}(\alpha - \zeta^{\pi(h)}\beta) = \prod_{h \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}}(\alpha - \zeta^h\beta) = G_n.$$
This is clear since $\zeta^{\pi(h)}$ run through each primitive $n$-th roots of unity exactly once as $h$ runs through $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.

Now to see why the symmetry implies that $G_n$ is an integer. The numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are Galois conjugates over $\mathbb{Q}$, and moreover they are algebraic integers. Likewise the primitive $n$-th roots of unity are algebraic integers and Galois conjugate to each other. Therefore $G_n$ is an algebraic integer in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D},\zeta)$. Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are Galois conjugates and likewise for the roots of unity, any field embedding $\sigma \colon \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D},\zeta) \to \mathbb{C}$ fixes $G_n$ by the symmetry properties. This implies that $G_n$ is rational. But since $G_n$ is also an algebraic integer, $G_n$ must actually be an integer.

Comment: Could you express the last paragraph in more elementary terms?

Comment: @SebastianGarrido Are you familiar with Galois theory? The implication that being symmetric in $\alpha,\beta$ and the roots of unity implies $G_n$ is rational is a Galois theoretic statement.

Comment: Not familiar with it.

Comment: Is there anywhere I can read on that specific statement you made ? I can use that to backtrack and become familiar with the parts of Galois theory I need.

Comment: @SebastianGarrido Well it follows from the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, which will be in any textbook that covers Galois theory.